# How do I set a static variable on a setter for a trigger wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, custom-controls

In my custom control, I have two Toggle buttons next to each other in my control template and I am trying to set a color to the background of the whole custom control when one or the other ToggleButton's Is pressed on.

Here is my code for understanding:

```
<local:SplitButtonModel.Template>
     <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:SplitButtonModel">

          <ControlTemplate.Resources>
               <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                         <Setter.Value>
                              <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                   <Rectangle x:Name="rect" Fill="Transparent" Stroke="#00000000"/>
                                   <ContentPresenter SnapToDevicePixels="{TemplatedBinding SnapToDevicePixels}" 
                                                     HorizontalAlignment="{TemplatedBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                                     VerticalAlignment="{TemplatedBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                                                     RecognizeAccessKey="True"/>
                                   <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                             <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="rect" Value="Red"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                   </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                              </ControlTemplate>
                         </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
               </Style>
          </ControlTemplate.Resources>


          <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplatedBinding Background}" 
                  BorderBrush="{TemplatedBinding BorderBrush}" 
                  BorderThickness="{TemplatedBinding BorderThickness}">
      
               <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="15"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ToggleButton Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <ToggleButton Grid.Column="1"/>
               </Grid>
          </Border>
          <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="Red"/>
               </Trigger>
          </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
     </ControlTemplate>
</local:SplitButtonModel.Template>
```

So within the template where I set the background to red, it doesn't work because IsPressed is bound to the ToggleButton and it will never get called within the main template. Now if I set the Rectangle "rect" Fill property to Red on IsPressed, that will work fine but it will only make the ToggleButton being pressed Red, while I want both ToggleButton's triggered even though the other one is not being pressed on.

I was thinking of creating a static class as below:

```
public static class GlobalHelper
{
     public static bool ButtonPressed = false;
}
```

Then I would set the trigger as below:

```
<Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
     <Setter Property="{Binding Source="{x:Static local:GlobalHelper.ButtonPressed}}" Value="True"/>
</Trigger>
```

But that doesn't work, so what would be a way to modify the static value so then in the maintemplate I can access it using a DataTrigger and depending if it is true or false, I can set the Background to Red?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use DataTriggers, connected to ToggleButtons IsPressed property, inside UserControl template:

```
<Border x:Name="border"
        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="15"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ToggleButton Grid.Column="0" x:Name="b1"/>
        <ToggleButton Grid.Column="1" x:Name="b2"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPressed, ElementName=b1}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="Red"/>
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPressed, ElementName=b2}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="Red"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

using global static variable doesn't make sense because it will affact *all* userControls, instead of the one currently pressed.